# Svg animation with d: path

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to animate my svg with `path` property by following [this](https://codepen.io/jorgeatgu/pen/bEEemM) codepen, but my animation path is not smooth and going with some weird steps. Is there something wrong with `path` values or what am I doing wrong here ?

```css
.p-4 path {
  d: path("");
  fill: #ff9fba;
  animation-name: dash;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    d: path("");
  }
  25% {
    d: path("M-375.047,1034.989a3.005,3.005,0,0,1-.562-.053A3,3,0,0,1-378,1031.43c3.037-16.029,8.67-25.866,16.742-29.239,9.747-4.073,19.479,2.47,23.143,4.933l.872.572a3.033,3.033,0,0,1,1.216,4.057,2.967,2.967,0,0,1-3.985,1.266c-.29-.15-.788-.47-1.451-.915-2.931-1.97-10.715-7.2-17.482-4.376-6.009,2.511-10.559,11.094-13.161,24.82A3,3,0,0,1-375.047,1034.989Z");
  }
  50% {
    d: path("M-375.047,1034.989a3.005,3.005,0,0,1-.562-.053A3,3,0,0,1-378,1031.43c3.037-16.029,8.67-25.866,16.742-29.239,9.747-4.073,19.479,2.47,23.143,4.933l.872.572c2.935,1.514,5.3,1.92,7.007,1.2,3.235-1.366,4.915-6.892,6.265-11.331l3.13.02,2.61,1.726c-1.714,5.637-3.848,12.653-9.671,15.113-3.426,1.447-7.5.975-12.11-1.4-.29-.15-.788-.469-1.451-.915-2.931-1.97-10.715-7.2-17.482-4.376-6.009,2.511-10.559,11.094-13.161,24.82A3,3,0,0,1-375.047,1034.989Z");
  }
  75% {
    d: path("M-375.047,1034.989a3.005,3.005,0,0,1-.562-.053A3,3,0,0,1-378,1031.43c3.037-16.029,8.67-25.866,16.742-29.239,9.747-4.073,19.479,2.47,23.143,4.933l.872.572c2.935,1.514,5.3,1.92,7.007,1.2,3.235-1.366,4.915-6.892,6.265-11.331l3.273-.478-2.89-.8c2.144-7.713,7.106-11.175,14.747-10.291a3,3,0,0,1,2.635,3.325,3,3,0,0,1-3.325,2.635c-5.923-.685-7.377,2.705-8.276,5.937l-.423,1.42c-1.714,5.637-3.848,12.653-9.671,15.113-3.426,1.447-7.5.975-12.11-1.4-.29-.15-.788-.469-1.451-.915-2.931-1.97-10.715-7.2-17.482-4.376-6.009,2.511-10.559,11.094-13.161,24.82A3,3,0,0,1-375.047,1034.989Z");
  }
  100% {
    d: path("M-375.047,1034.989a3.005,3.005,0,0,1-.562-.053A3,3,0,0,1-378,1031.43c3.037-16.029,8.67-25.866,16.742-29.239,9.747-4.073,19.479,2.47,23.143,4.933l.872.572c2.935,1.514,5.3,1.92,7.007,1.2,3.235-1.366,4.915-6.892,6.265-11.331l3.273-.478-2.89-.8c2.144-7.713,7.106-11.175,14.747-10.291,3.293.381,11.241-.41,13.927-15.954a3,3,0,0,1,3.467-2.445A3,3,0,0,1-289,971.059c-3.658,21.167-16.638,21.342-20.529,20.892-5.923-.685-7.377,2.705-8.276,5.937l-.423,1.42c-1.714,5.637-3.848,12.653-9.671,15.113-3.426,1.447-7.5.975-12.11-1.4-.29-.15-.788-.469-1.451-.915-2.931-1.97-10.715-7.2-17.482-4.376-6.009,2.511-10.559,11.094-13.161,24.82A3,3,0,0,1-375.047,1034.989Z");
  }
}
```

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="89.095" height="67.442" viewBox="0 0 89.095 67.442" class="usp_overlap_photo p-4">
                                <path id="home-usp4-p4" transform="translate(378.051 -967.547)"/>
                              </svg>
```

Comment: The paths must have the same numbers and types of command letters. Your paths appear at the very least to be different lengths.

Comment: @RobertLongson, Do you know how can I get the correct paths values ? Because originally I only have the path value for `100%`. I generated other path values in design tool by removing other paths (cutting length) and generate them as svg again and copy their path values, i dont know if that's the right way to do it.

Comment: Please read about [How SVG Line Animation Works](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it be ok if the shape was turned into a path with a stroke instead of an outline of the shape with a fill?

Here I refactured the shape and animate the stroke-dasharray instead of the d attribute.

```css
.p-4 path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ff9fba;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  animation-name: dash;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  }
  25% {
    stroke-dasharray: 25 100;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 50 100;
  }
  75% {
    stroke-dasharray: 75 100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 100 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="usp_overlap_photo p-4">
  <path transform="translate(5 5)" id="home-usp4-p4" d="M 0,63 C 0,63 5,23 32,38 43,45 49,42 53,33 57,24 56,19 69,19 82,20 85,0 85,0" pathLength="100" stroke-dashoffset="0"/>
</svg>
```

Well, then we don't need all the keys in the keyframe:

```css
.p-4 path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ff9fba;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  animation-name: dash;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 100 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="usp_overlap_photo p-4">
  <path transform="translate(5 5)" id="home-usp4-p4" d="M 0,63 C 0,63 5,23 32,38 43,45 49,42 53,33 57,24 56,19 69,19 82,20 85,0 85,0" pathLength="100" stroke-dashoffset="0"/>
</svg>
```